# when trying to connect ibm db2 using nodejs i am getting Database name not found error

Tags: node.js, database, db2, node-modules

1. Installed nodejs
2. Installed ibm_db
3. Downloaded the nodedb2test.js file
4. Changed the database details as per my DB2 database
5. Ran this file.
   Got the error

[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "xyz          " was not found at the remot e node.  SQLSTATE=08004

Comment: This is almost certainly a case of the connection details being incorrect.  We can't really help since we don't know the connection details you used, nor do we know the correct details for your database.  Look at the connection string for something that is working to connect to that database, and make sure everything is the same.

Comment: hi.. but i have given the credentials correctly without any space but after my database name in the error shown i can see some space   error:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "xyzzz           " was not found at the node.  SQLSTATE=08004

Comment: Hi .. now i am getting this error error:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP
".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "123.40.123.12".  Communication func
tion detecting the error: "selectForRecvTimeout".  Protocol specific error code(s): "0", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001. Can someone help me resolving this.